# why i get all false on the most informative features

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I have train set and test set, and I want to test the most informative features, but I get the result is all false. Here is train set and test set:

```
train = [
    ('باجو ساي بيرو', 'biru'),
    ('كتيك هاري ترڠ لاڠيت بيرو', 'biru'),
    ('لاڠيت برورنا بيرو كتيك هاري چره', 'biru'),
    ('ورنا لاوت بيرو', 'biru'),
    ('اهلي بيرو دان اهلي لجنة', 'biro'),
    ('بيرو سوكن دان ريكرياسي برتيكد ممبري كفهمن دان كسدران تنتڠ كڤنتيڠن 
    سوكن', 'biro'),
    ("بيرو تاجان امت ڤنتيڠ دالم سسبواه ڤرساتوان", 'biro'),
    ('ستياڤ بيرو دان لجنة ممڤوڽاءي توڬس يڠ ڤنتيڠ', 'biro'),
]

test = [
    ('باجو اديق ورنا بيرو', 'biru'),
    ('اهلي ڤرساتوان يڠ ممڬڠ جاوتن سباڬاي بيرو منداڤت باڽق كلبيهن', 
    'biro'),
    ('ساي ممڬڠ جاوتن بيرو تاجان دالم ڤرساتوان', 'biro'),
    ("لاڠيت دان لاوت برورنا بيرو", 'biru'),
    ('ڤين چئڬو ورنا بيرو تله هيلڠ', 'biru'),
    ('ستياڤ بيرو ڤرلو تڬس دالم ممبري ارهن', 'biro'),
    ("بيرو دان لجنة ملقساناكن فوڠسي سڤرتي سبواه جاوتنكواس", 'biro'),
    ('بيرو ترجمهن نڬارا ڤرلو دتوبوهكن سڬرا', 'biro'),
    ("بيرو سوكن امت ڤنتيڠ", 'biro'),
    ("بيرو دان لجنة دسارنكن منجالنكن توڬس دڠن تلوس", 'biro')
]

cl.show_informative_features(10)
```

I've tried to run the code `cl.show_informative_features(10)`

I expect the output will be true and the ratios also true.

Comment: i get the output is like this

Most Informative Features
           contains(دان) = False          biru : biro   =      3.0 : 1.0
           contains(لاڠيت) = False         biro : biru   =      1.8 : 1.0
           contains(ڤنتيڠ) = False        biru : biro   =      1.8 : 1.0
           contains(هاري) = False         biro : biru   =      1.8 : 1.0
           contains(كتيك) = False         biro : biru   =      1.8 : 1.0
           contains(لجنة) = False         biru : biro   =      1.8 : 1.0
           contains(امت) = False          biru : biro   =      1.3 : 1.0

Comment: please format your code properly. and add tags, not just python-3.x, this seems to be related to some library (maybe NLTK idk)